Google Sheets - Repeat whole Row n times based on value input
I have a table of fixtures with scores input.
Is there a way to have the row repeat based on the greater value of the 2 scores input?
Example below - need the rows repeated 2,3,4,2,1 times respectively so I can input scorers under Home Scorer and Away Scorer.
DATE            HOME            HS   v  AS  AWAY            Home Scorer Away Scorer
9-Sep-23    AFC Fylde   0    -  2   Aldershot Town
28-Aug-23   AFC Fylde   3    -  3   Altrincham
17-Feb-24   AFC Fylde   2    -  4   Barnet
26-Sep-23   AFC Fylde   2    -  2   Boreham Wood
27-Jan-24   AFC Fylde   1    -  0   Bromley
I have found something similar which would be great but can't make it work for me. @Harun24hr
Repeat whole row N times based on column value in Google Sheets
Can anyone help please?
I have tried using the answer in the link provided but cannot quite make it work. What does the MATCH("zzz" section do?

Show your desired result. You may share a sample google-sheet link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZPIYG1ndlXmPb_MC-K2LOqpumQe8ir-aqOeipQqD9Y8/edit?usp=sharing
Input Goalscorers tab

Can you make a small file then indicate your input data and then show output result you wish.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13wK7N5Ra1b8x0fic4bzKVPqfgW8Wlu42q4YW2yze_1o/edit?usp=sharing
Hope that is something you can work with.


Here's one approach you may test out:
=reduce(D1:I1,F2:index(F:F,match(,0/(F:F<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,chooserows(offset(c,,-2,,6),sequence(max(1,c,offset(c,,2)),1,1,0)))))



If the score is 0 - 0,then that specific row is repeated just 1 time. Let us know if you need that differently or so...


That looks excellent, I will do some testing to confirm. Thank you for now.
